# Can a complete pluripolar set be a single point?

Tags: several-complex-variables, potential-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$ be a plurisubharmonic function which is not identically $-\infty$.The set $\mathcal{P}:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}^n:f(z)=-\infty\}$ is called a complete pluripolar set.

My question is:is it posibble that $\mathcal{P}$ is a single point?Why?

Any answers are appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it is possible. Take the maximum of $\log |z_k|$.

Comment: @Yes:What do you mean by 'maximun'?The locus of minus infinity of $\log|z_k|$ is $\{z_k=0\}\subset \mathbb{C}^n$,which is a variety,not a single point.

Comment: @Yes You mean $\max\{\log|z_1|,\ldots,\log|z_n|\}$.I see.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every finite set is complete pluripolar. If $E = \{ w_1, \ldots, w_n \}$, take for example
$$
u(z) = \sum_{j=1}^n \log \| z-w_j \|.
$$